# php/ajax form not sending info

Tags: php, ajax

I almost have it but I am missing something. The form is being sent and the row is being created but there is not data. It is blank (both the email and the database). I know it is something simple I am missing but I cannot figure it out.

There is no errors, the form disappears like it is supposed to. I am getting an email but there is no userdata in it. It creates a row in the database, but again there is no data being put in the row.

If anyone can look at my code below and tell me what I am missing to make the inputed info be seen, I would sure appreciate it.

I have searched and searched and tried different things but I cannot get it to send the info.

AJAX_Quote.php

```
     <?php

    include_once('class/class_email.php');

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","password","database");
$FName = $_POST['Form_FName'];
$LName = $_POST['Form_LName'];
$Email = $_POST['Form_Email'];
$Company = $_POST['Form_Company'];
$Number = $_POST['Form_Number'];
$Comments = $_POST['Form_Comments'];
$EID = $_POST['eid'];



    //$SQL_GetEquipment = "SELECT * FROM `new_equip` WHERE `id`='$EID' LIMIT 1;";
    //$R_GetEquipment = mysql_query($SQL_GetEquipment, $Link);
    //$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($R_GetEquipment);
    $SQL_GetEquipment = "SELECT * FROM `new_equip` WHERE `id`='$EID' LIMIT 1;";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$SQL_GetEquipment);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $EmailBody = "$FName $LName has requested a quote from NAPE on Item $EID\n 

    Information on quote request: \n
    Name: $FName $LName \n
    Email: $Email \n
    Company: $Company \n
    Number: $Number  \n 
    Comments: $Comments  \n 
    \n
    Information Requested for: {$row['itemname']}\n
    The URL to {$row['itemname']} is: http://www.domain.com/new-product.php?Item=$EID
    \n
    Click to send a quote now:\n
    http://www.domain.com/Admin/send-quote.php?id=$EID ";

    $e = new email();

    //First value is the URL of your server, the second the port number
    $e->set_server( 'mail.domain.com', 26);

    //First value is your username, then your password
    $e->set_auth('noreply@domain.com', 'nape112233');

    //Set the "From" setting for your e-mail. The Name will be base64 encoded
    $e->set_sender( 'Quote Requested', 'noreply@domain.com' );

    //for one recipient
    $send_to = array('email@gmail.com');
    //you may also specify multiple recipients by creating an array like this:
    //$send_to = array('foo1@localhost.local', 'foo2@localhost.local', 'foo3@localhost.local');

    $subject = 'Quote Request from NAPE';
    $body = "$EmailBody";
    if( $e->mail($send_to, $subject, $body, $headers) == true )
    {
      //message was received by the smtp server
      //['last'] tends to contain the queue id so I like to save that string in the database
      echo 'last: '.htmlspecialchars($e->srv_ret['last']).'';
    }else{
      //something went wrong
      echo 'all: '.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($e->srv_ret['all'])).'';
      echo 'full:'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($e->srv_ret['full'])).'';
    }
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users (`fname`,`lname`,`email`,`company`,`number`) 
    VALUES ('$FName','$LName','$Email','$Company','$Number')");

    ?>
```

My form code

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post" style="width:600px">
        <br />
        <table width="80%">
            <tr>
                <td width="36%">*First Name:</td>
                <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="61%">
                    <input type="text" id="Form_FName" name="Form_FName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="36%">*Last Name:</td>
                <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="61%">
                    <input type="text" id="Form_LName" name="Form_LName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="36%">Company Name:</td>
                <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="61%">
                    <input type="text" id="Form_Company" name="Form_Company" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>*Your E-Mail:</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Form_Email" name="Form_Email" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="36%">*Phone Number:</td>
                <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="61%">
                    <input type="text" id="Form_Number" name="Form_Number" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="36%" h>Comments:</td>
                <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="61%">
                    <textarea id="Form_Comments" name="Form_Comments" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="36%" align="center" colspan="3">
                    <button id="send">Request Quote</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" colospan="3">
                    <b><?php echo $itemname; ?></b>
                    <br />
                    <br /> Manufacturer: <?php echo $manufactuer;?>
                    <br /> Model: <?php echo $model;?>
                    <br /> Category: <?php echo $category;?>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- basic fancybox setup -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
            $(".modalbox").fancybox();
            $("#contact").submit(function () {
                    return false;
                });
            $("#send").on("click", function () {

                    {
                        // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
                        // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
                        $("#send").replaceWith("<em>Your request has been sent...</em>");

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "AJAX_Quote.php",
                            data: $("#idForm").serialize(),                                
                            success: setTimeout(function () { parent.$.fancybox.close(); }, 2000) 


                        });
                    }
                });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: what result do you expect? what result are you getting instead? "form not sending info" is not very descriptive. is your code erroring out? is it sending mail? what is the result of your query? what does `$_POST` look like? What return code are you getting for the ajax request?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I explained it the best I could. I am new to php. There are no errors, the form disappears like it is supposed to. I am getting an email but there is no userdata in it. It creates a row in the database, but again there is no data being put in the row.

Comment: ah, no problem. welcome to stack overflow! an important quality of any good question is to describe clearly what result you are getting vs what result you expect. you should include that information in the question.

Comment: I actually have learned so much from this board. The members and other questions I search have taught me 80% of what I know about php/mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of your form inputs is of the format `name="Form_FName"` but in your PHP you refer to them as `$FName = $_POST['fname'];`. The correct PHP would be `$FName = $_POST['Form_FName'];`

Also I suggest escaping your input fields to avoid SQL injection. Check out mysqli_real_escape_string.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: I changed the php but the email still is coming in without the values.

Comment: Instead of turning the data into JSON, remove your current data and dataType from your JS and replace them with: `data: $("#contact").serialize(),`, again making sure the input field names match their $_POST[''] ids in the PHP.

Comment: I appreciate it, I replaced the code. Still blank though.. I edited my original post with the updated code.

Comment: I apologize I made a correction after you viewed my comment. Make sure to address the form #contact and not #idForm

Comment: That worked. I am now getting the info in the email.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to add the "code box" around the code at the end of this comment.  -  but the info is being put into the database. You dont know how much I appreciate your help. 
One more thing I see, is the item ID isnt showing up. I have it where it links to the item page ($EID) but that part isnt showing in the email. This section '(The URL to {$row['itemname']} is: http://www.domain.com/new-product.php?Item=$EID)'

Comment: There is no EID being sent by the form. If I understand what your are saying, you want `$EID = $_GET['Item'];`, which will set $EID to whatever follows '?Item=' in your url. If this ?Item= only exists on the contact page, you will have to forward the value, either by editing your JS to `url: "AJAX_Quote.php?Item=<? echo $_GET['Item']; ?>",` or adding an element to your form `<input type="hidden" name="EID" value="<? echo $_GET['Item']; ?>">`, which would then be fetched in the result PHP script using `$_POST['EID'];`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Again, You dont know how much I appreciate your time and help with this. This is a great board with a lot of helpful members. Thanks again.